# Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0. Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

So I switched to a flutter beta channel recently flutter 1.26.0 - 17.6.pre, I had already done a web project that ran properly, So recently I tried doing a mobile app project, and it built the first time and after that I kept getting this error log from gradle.

```
[+155045 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[  +55 ms] * What went wrong:
[        ] org/apache/http/pool/AbstractConnPool
[        ] * Try:
[        ] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run
with --scan to get full insights.
[        ] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[  +63 ms] Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
[        ] Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
[        ] See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
[        ] BUILD FAILED in 2m 29s
[+3846 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... (completed in 158.9s)
[ +204 ms] Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Still having this issue

Comment: "Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings." maybe we can help you after you provide more information related to your problem.

Comment: Share your `build.gradle` file. Even better, open it in Android Studio and let the linter show you your errors. This question needs more debugging details.

Answer (score 0):

things ive done so far:

1. run with --no-sound-null-safety and --verbose
2. find dependencies that complain and check for updates, then update to latest in pubspec
3. one dependency complained about android min sdk version in gradle.build, so i updated accordingly

now i can build to my test machine and work out the runtime bugs!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is stating that some deprecated features were used in the project (probably a package) causing the build to fail since those deprecated features are incompatible with your current gradle version, 7.0.

Try to lower your gradle version by changing the field "distributionUrl" (located at $project_dir/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties) to https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.4.1-all.zip or replace "gradle-6.4.1" with any other lower available versions.

like so:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/${your-chosen-gradle-version}-all.zip
```

This will cause you computer to download the gradle version specified in the distribution url and use that to build your app in the next build.