# Flutter not building the android dependencies

Tags: flutter, gradle

Folks,

I am re-building an already built flutter application upon changing of the laptop. However I have strangely observed that the dependencies that we mention in the pubspec, not all of them are getting compiled. Those ones which has native dependencies and eventually have android code base in the dependencies fail to compile. I am cluless how this is happening and where should i look forward to get this going. The only error I get is as below. The contentious dependencies were share and connectivity

```
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
[   +5 ms] warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
[   +1 ms] warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
[   +1 ms] error: warnings found and -Werror specified
[ +190 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[        ] * What went wrong:
[        ] Execution failed for task ':share:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
[  +97 ms] > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
[        ] * Try:
[        ] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full
insights.
[   +3 ms] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[   +1 ms] BUILD FAILED in 1m 41s
[   +1 ms] Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
[   +1 ms] Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
[   +5 ms] See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
[        ] 410 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 406 up-to-date
[ +794 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... (completed in 103.9s)
[   +9 ms] Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
[   +4 ms] "flutter run" took 1,08,191ms.
[   +9 ms]
#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:14:3)
#1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:607:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:977:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:836:33)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart)
#5      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:29)
#6      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
#7      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
#8      _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1630:10)
#9      runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1550:10)
#10     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:18)
#11     FlutterCommand.run (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:825:20)
#12     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:197:27)
#13     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:335:21)
#14     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
#15     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
#16     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
#17     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
#18     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
#19     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
#20     Future._asyncCompleteWithValue.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:567:7)
#21     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
#22     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
#23     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
#24     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
#25     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#26     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#27     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)
#28     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:169:5)


[   +6 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 3ms
[   +3 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[        ] Shutdown hook priority 4
[  +12 ms] Shutdown hooks complete
[   +1 ms] exiting with code 1
```

I am using flutter 1.22.6 stable
dart 2.10.5
Gradle 6.5

I have tried it out with 1.22.3 and also with 1.20.4, still this is not taking me anywhere. All that it ends up is not compiling the dependencies having android code in it. **gradlew assembleDebug --info** and likes of it has resulted in me understanding that the java symbols are not created which eventually are not found by the compilation script, hence it is generating error.

Answer (score 1):

things ive done so far:

1. run with --no-sound-null-safety and --verbose
2. find dependencies that complain and check for updates, then update to latest in pubspec
3. one dependency complained about android min sdk version in gradle.build, so i updated accordingly

now i can build to my test machine and work out the runtime bugs!

[Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0. Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66469170/deprecated-gradle-features-were-used-in-this-build-making-it-incompatible-with/68328349#68328349)